# Rails i18n inflections for error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, language-specifications

Does anyone know how to define a gender for the attributes in a model? So when error messages appear I can give them a specific gender such as:

**La** *dirección* no puede estar en blanco ( Address can't be left blank) - Address has a female article in Spanish

**El** *usuario* no puede estar en blanco ( User can't be left blank) - User has a masculine article in Spanish

All of this obviously using i18n inflections in a specific rails /config/locales/language.yml file

I'm working with the actual attributes from my model so when I use things such as:

```
app/views/tableName/new.html.erb

<% if @tableName.errors.any? %>
<h2>Los siguientes errores no permitieron que se salvara este elemento</h2>
<ul>
  <% @tableName.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

I can get a article (based on gender) before the actual message, the problem is that as you can see I really don't have access directly to the attributes.